# How to prevent Microsoft Lync adding startup entry in Windows?

Tags: windows, boot, lync

Microsoft lync makes my laptop boot very slowly and if I disable it from startup, the laptop boots fine and quick. However the issue is, if I start lync again, it puts an entry to startup. So I end up disabling again and again before every boot. I try to put my laptop into sleep only as much possible, however there are many times I need to start up. So, please suggest how to do any of the following?

1. How to remove a program from start up, programatically or a windows setting?
2. How to disable Microsoft lync to stop putting an entry into startup?

Comment: There should be a way to turn it off in its options. Else see http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/yuval14/archive/2011/10/27/how-to-disable-automatic-startup-of-lync-2010-client.aspx

Comment: Yes manually we have. I need to do it with a program or automatically in any manner, with a script  that would run before the system shuts down or something.

Comment: You could write a batch-script to do the registry hack that post suggests.

Comment: Cool, I did not have to write a script. I just made the flag to 0 and it does not write to start up anymore and also its removed from startup. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also it appears the it is kind of hack that, the system entry still shows lync as startup task and lync doesn't get start at start up. :).

Comment: Open Lync. Then Tools > Options > Personalize > Uncheck the 'Automatically start Lync when windows starts' and it should get solved. http://imgur.com/YnXXsFn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off logging in your Lync client.  The logging functionality is what is causing the startup delay, not the client itself. Only use logging during diagnostics.

Comment: How to turn of logging?

Answer (score 14):

You can also configure Lync so that it doesn't start up with Windows. On the sign-in screen, click the configure gear and choose Tools -> Options. Select Personal and un-check "Automatically start Lync when I log on to Windows"

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has dodged this to allow Lync to continue annoying
users. The options to Change has become **"Do you want a quick or
slow repair?"**.

1. Go to Run (or <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
2. Type `msconfig.exe` and Click OK.
3. Go to *Start Up options*, then  go to *Task Manager* and change Lync to ge to *Disabled*.

Seems to work after rebooting once.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means.  It looks like you are asking me to run msconfig, and do nothing with it, then you bring up a completely separate program - the task manager - and change some setting that I can't locate.

I don't see an item called "Task Manager" in the Startup options of msconfig

Answer (score 1):

You can also uninstall Lync if you don't need it (part of the Microsoft Office).

Go to the `Control Panel` - `Programs and Feature`s and right click on `Microsoft Office 2013` and choose `Change`.

[image]

Now you can continue to `Add or Remove Featues` and uncheck the Lync feature:

[image]