# How to turn off Lync 2010 startup?

Tags: boot, microsoft-office-2010, lync-2010

I don't want Lync 2010 to run automatically when I start Windows 7.

How can I do that?

It seems nowhere I could do it in the `Option`

[image]

Comment: run msconfig/autoruns and look if you can disable it here.

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked similar in superuser before, you may like to check.

[How to prevent Microsoft Lync adding startup entry in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/571057/how-to-prevent-microsoft-lync-adding-startup-entry-in-windows)

Meanwhile, it would be a difficult if you are not comfort with registry edit, worth a try if you do:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/yuval14/2011/10/27/how-to-disable-automatic-startup-of-lync-2010-client/

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points from the link in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. Please extract the solution from the link and I'll make it accepted when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing the adjustment for your own account, or per user, it's under the Options**Personal** section, not the General.

Look there and uncheck "Automatically start Lync when I log in to Windows".

That should keep it suppressed unless your profile is blown away.